# How to deallocate pointer-to-pointer-types that point to pointer-types in heap that point to other objects in heap?

Tags: c++

So I decided to have some pointer fun tonight :)

```
CursorHBList::CursorHBList(UINT iNumHB)
    :m_ppCursorHB(nullptr)
    ,m_iNumHB(iNumHB)
{
    if (iNumHB != 0) {
        m_ppCursorHB = new CursorHitBox* [iNumHB];
    }   
}
```

so you can see, I've now dynamically allocated pointer-types.

Those pointers will each point to another (single) object in the heap. (later on, not in code sample)

So I've been wondering if I should delete all the pointer-to-object-types pointed to by the pointer-to-pointer-type first, and then delete[] the pointer-to-pointer-type?

Or is there a better way?

EDIT: Without using smart pointers...

Comment: Yes there is a better way. Like using a vector of smart pointers.

Comment: Without using smart pointers...

Comment: What do you mean when you say statically allocated on the heap?

Comment: @Mooing Duck Just specifying that it's not dynamically allocated

Comment: @xcrypt: Seth disagrees with me, so just to be sure: Are the "statically allocated objects on the heap but not dynamically allocated" declared like `CursorHitBox hitboxes[100];` or like `CursorHitBox* newbox = new CursorHitBox();` or like `CursorHitBox* newbox = new CursorHitBox[100];`?

Comment: @Mooing Duck I might mix up some naming, I'm not entirely sure.

What I meant with static allocation: int* pNumber = new int;
What I meant with dynamic allocation: int* pNumber = new int[100];

CursorHitBox* pHitBox[100]; would also be static allocation since it is determined compiletime. dynamic allocation isn't.

But don't take my word for it... I'm not entirely sure

Comment: @Mooing Duck I looked it up. I was wrong. both int* pNum = new int and int* pNum = new int[100] are examples of dynamic memory allocation. I wonder though, how do we name the difference then?

Comment: @xcrypt: one is an array, one is a single element.  They're both dynamically allocated on the heap.  It goes out of scope when you call `delete`. A local variable is a variable _not_ declared with `new`, but in an object or function.  It goes out of scope when the function ends or object goes out of scope.  A static variable is _not_ declared with `new`, and is either not in an object or function, or is declared with the `static` keyword.  It goes out of scope when the program ends.

Comment: @Mooing Duck I knew all of that though, I just thought there was a concept difference between "new x" and "new x[10]". Nvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, a better way would be using a container of smart pointers.

However, since you can't use smart pointers (I don't know why because all a smart pointer is is a very simple class, you could write your own), you'll need to loop through the array and `delete` each pointer, then `delete[]` the array, in that order. That's just what you have to do when you manage your own memory.

Comment: All right, thanks. I don't really like to work with smart pointers, because I like to see what's going on. I might start using them later on, when I get experienced.

Comment: @xcrypt I'm the same way, I almost always write my own version of a class before using the C++ standard library version. This is C++, it's good to know exactly what's happening.

Comment: The OP clarified that the pointed at objects are _not_ dynamically allocated, in which case you should _not_ call `delete` on each pointer, right?  just `delete[]` the array.

Comment: @Mooing it's kind of a condradiction, he says "Those pointers will each point to another (static-allocated) object in the heap." I think, however, that he just misunderstands what "static-allocted" means, and that the "object in the heap" is accurate, and means that those objects _are_ dynamically allocated.